# Не переведено "Remove wiki" в действиях модератора

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, общие-сообщения

Не переведено сообщение

> Remove wiki

в действиях модератора:

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13156

Будет на сайте в свежих сборках. Текущая rev 2020.11.24.38066

Comment: "Снять признак общего"? Ну хоть не призрак, но звучит странно.

Comment: @Qwertiy критикуешь — предлагай :) это я уже не первый раз говорю

Comment: А как раньше переводилось?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле "раньше"? На скриншоте же перевода нет не просто так.

Comment: может "снять статус общего"?

Comment: @Danis можно и так. Если что Qwertiy сам сможет перевод подправить как ему нравится.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но в старом интерфейсе оно ведь как-то называлось. Можно оттуда найти перевод?

Comment: @Qwertiy а был какой-то старый интерфейс? Я не в курсе. Наверное, "признак" всё же [действительно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbcYy.png) надо заменить на "статус". Подправил перевод. Ждите новых сборок.

Comment: До того, как заглавные буквы появились, вероятно, какой-то перевод был.

Comment: @Qwertiy всё что нашлось в переводах по "remove wiki" без учёта регистра я привёл на картинке в комментарии выше.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а если оригинальная фраза больше не используется на сайте, её перевод где-то остаётся? И можно ли его найти по этой фразе?

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде как [должна оставаться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356336/extra-will-in-message-from-ui/356410#comment1190909_356410).